# Prevent back button from going back to previous page for an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Using the following function to prevent users from going back to previous page if the page they are on currently has the id #home. But this function doesn't even fire off. No alerts. Nothing wrong with the link to script file as I have other scripts running fine on that file.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    alert("Back button pressed");
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    var activePageId = activePage[0].id;
    alert(activePageId);
    if (activePageId == 'home') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have created a custom event there is no `onbackbutton` event I know of. You are after `onbeforeunload`

Clients don't like it when you block navigation. You should consider other solutions to you problem rather than block navigation. Sure as .... the next thing the client will do is close the tab and a good chance you will never see a session with that client again.